# Swift using NSStatusBar statusItemWithLength and NSVariableStatusItemLength

Tags: cocoa, swift

I'm trying to rewrite the following code from the [Status Bar Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/Tasks/creatingitems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000996-BBCDAGHB) in Swift.

```
NSStatusBar *bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];

theItem = [bar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
[theItem retain];

[theItem setTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Tablet",@"")];
...
```

My Swift code so far:

```
let bar = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar()

let sm = bar.statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)
sm.title = "Tablet"
...
```

The problem is that the `statusItemWithLength` method in Swift excepts `CGFloat` but `NSVariableStatusItemLength` is defined as `CInt` in Swift. I see the following error:

```
'CInt' is not convertible to 'CGFloat'
```

Definition in Xcode:

```
var NSVariableStatusItemLength: CInt { get }
var NSSquareStatusItemLength: CInt { get }

class NSStatusBar : NSObject {

    class func systemStatusBar() -> NSStatusBar!

    func statusItemWithLength(length: CGFloat) -> NSStatusItem!
    ...
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For Beta 1 & 2 you can manually convert NSVariableStatusItemLength from CInt to the required CGFloat like so:

```
let sm = bar.statusItemWithLength( CGFloat(NSVariableStatusItemLength) )
```

In Beta 3 NSVariableStatusItemLength is now a CGFloat, but due to a linker error (bug) you have to use 
-1 instead of NSVariableStatusItemLength and 
-2 instead of NSSquareStatusItemLength

```
let sm = bar.statusItemWithLength( -1 )
```

Thanks to suzhi and gui_dos for figuring this out!

Comment: Thanks, this works. But basically it is somehow odd that a enum has wrong type...

Comment: This solution stopped working for me as of Beta 6, with build error `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_NSSquareStatusItemLength"`.

Comment: Er, yes. Don't know where the 6 came from.

Comment: I have the same problem with beta 3 and I am stuck.

Comment: I found this: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1001121#1001121
Using "-1" oder "-2" is a workaround for now.

Comment: On 10.11 Beta and Xcode 7.0 beta 4 `NSVariableStatusItemLength` is available and there's no more link error.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, with the Beta 3 release you can pass the Int constant directly. For instance:

```
statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-1) // NSVariableStatusItemLength
```

https://github.com/gui-dos/Guigna/blob/181f9db1056dece888dc29424cc2da79f8f284e3/Guigna-Swift/Guigna/GuignaAppDelegate.swift#L138